# Issue with adding Google authentication with exsitinng JWT Authorization for Blazor WASM

Tags: google-oauth, blazor-webassembly

I have API using JWT to  authorize calls from  Blazor WASM client. Users are authenticated by username and password and after successful authentication API sends back JWT.

I would like to add Google authentication whereby I could send google token to API and get back JWT with all user claims

I call google auth end point I am getting following error:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100] Unhandled exception rendering component: Specified cast is not valid. System.InvalidCastException: Specified is not valid. at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__0`3[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteUserAccount, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.OidcProviderOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=6.0.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].<AddRemoteAuthentication>b__0_0(IServiceProvider sp) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType).

When I comment my custom AuthenticationStateprovider Google Auth works fine i.e. I am receiving Google Token. How can I use a mix of JWT auth : username and password to get token from aPI and Google Auth when I can pass google token to API and receive JWT token too?